# Export MacOS Mail rules to Office 365 server

Tags: macos, mail.app, office-365, mail-rules

My company is moving our mail from an old IMAP server to an Office 365 server. I currently have dozens of mail rules for automatically filing messages into folders. I'm told that Office 365 can process rules on the server, which would be good because it would mean that the filing would be done even if my MacBook is offline (not common, as I only shut it down when traveling, but it would still be useful).

Is there any way to export selected rules from Mac Mail.app and import them onto the Office server? We have web access to the Office server through outlook.office.com.

I'll want to select the rules that are migrated, because I use the same mail client for my personal email, and those rules don't belong on the company server.